# CSS Grid - Responsive sidebar alignment

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make the sidebar logos to be aligned vertically with each other, the same for the texts. But it seems the the logos are been aligned only with the same itens in the row and not with the column.

I wanted to make each other aligned horizontally and vertically as the print shows.
I have a codepen sketch to doodle it [Codepen](https://codepen.io/LuizMosciaro/pen/OJoQbMj)

```
    <div id='sidebar'>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/001-menu.png" alt="menu-logo">
                    <span class="link-text">Menu</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/002-portfolio.png" alt="portfolio-logo">
                    <span class="link-text">Portfolio</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/003-investment.png" alt="strategies-logo">
                    <span class="link-text">Strategies</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/004-certificate.png" alt="deposit-logo">
                    <span class="link-text">Deposit/Withdraw</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/005-investor.png" alt="partnerProgram-logo">
                    <span class="link-text">Partner Program</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/007-property.png" alt="marketAnalysis-logo">
                    <span class="link-text">Market Analysis</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                    <img src="/icons/008-logout.png" alt="logout">
                    <span class="link-text">Logout</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

#sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidebar li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1rem;
}

.link-text {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


#sidebar:hover .link-text {
  display: block;
}

#sidebar li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#sidebar img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  width: 40px;
}
```

[image]

I tried to change the sidebar-link flex-direction to column but it makes the text to be below the logo.I want to do it just by using CSS and HTML.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i think is that you have to just add the following code in your css

```
#sidebar li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar img {
    min-width: 40px;
}

#sidebar ul { height: calc(100% - 64px);}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Would you also know how to make the last element at the most bottom position dynamically? 
I've tried this but couldnt work out.
#sidebar li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
}

Comment: just add this to your current codepen code `#sidebar ul { height: calc(100% - 64px);}`

Comment: I have updated the comment accordingly

Comment: remove `transform` from `#sidebar li:last-child`